# Get APIM access token using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to get an access token from an azure apim.

The token, when I retrieve from the Azure Portal (Azure portal -> APIM instance -> Management API -> Enable Management REST API -> Access Token -> Generate) looks like "SharedAccessSignature integration&2021022706..."

But when I use Get-AzApiManagementSsoToken the value returned looks different : "https://myapi.portal.azure-api.net:443/signin-sso?token=1%2620210128070..."

Is there a different powershell command to retrieve the Access Token similar to the one in the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `New-AzApiManagementUserToken` instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementusertoken?view=azps-5.4.0